# MySQL permissions -- can't create functions even with the 'CREATE ROUTINE' grant

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1044

When connecting to my server (from a different machine) I get

```
Error Code: 1044 Access denied for user 'username'@'%' to database 'dbname'
```

when I try to create a function. But when I look at my permissions

```
SHOW GRANTS FOR CURRENT_USER;
```

I get

```
'GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, CREATE, DROP, RELOAD, SHUTDOWN, PROCESS, FILE, REFERENCES, INDEX, ALTER, SHOW DATABASES, SUPER, CREATE TEMPORARY TABLES, LOCK TABLES, EXECUTE, REPLICATION SLAVE, REPLICATION CLIENT, CREATE ROUTINE ON *.* TO ''username''@''%'' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD ''--stripped--'' WITH GRANT OPTION'
```

In particular, this includes CREATE ROUTINE.  Why can't I make a function?  How can I change it so I can?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think there is a `CREATE FUNCTION` that is separate from `CREATE ROUTINE`. But either way, since it looks like your user has 100% full access anyway you could do:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO user@'%' INDENTIFIED BY 'password' WITH GRANT OPTION
```

However I would note it would be much better to set the '%' to 'localhost' and only access the database in this manner from a local machine (or at least a trusted IP). The lack of security with this could cause you trouble.

Definitely don't use this user/password to connect to the database from a web script!

**Edit**
I forgot: routines and functions have to be granted *globally*. Adding *.* tries to add the grant to the tables themselves which is why it doesn't work. Try:

```
GRANT ALTER ROUTINE,CREATE ROUTINE, EXECUTE ON * TO user@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'password'
```

There's a longer description of it here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/grant.html

Comment: MySQL gives an error when I try to grant CREATE FUNCTION.  I gave all privileges and now the current user grants (according to SHOW GRANTS FOR CURRENT_USER) are `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'username'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '--deleted--' WITH GRANT OPTION`, but I still can't create functions (same error).

Comment: As for security: I'm not using the script from localhost (see my first line), but your advice on limiting this seems good; maybe I'll restrict it to my IP address and localhost.  I'm certainly not using it from a web script!

Comment: OK, now SHOW GRANTS has `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'username'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '--deleted--' WITH GRANT OPTION` and `GRANT EXECUTE, CREATE ROUTINE, ALTER ROUTINE ON 'dbname'.* TO 'username'@'%'`, but I still get the same error if I try to create the function.

Comment: It shouldn't be 'dbname'.* it should just be '*'.

Comment: I didn't type 'dbname', that's just what it shows when I type `SHOW GRANTS FOR CURRENT_USER;`.

Comment: My bad ... hmmm. I thought the last thing would work since that's what's in the link I provided. Try giving your user permissions to the 'mysql' database.

Comment: OK, now SHOW GRANTS also has `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON 'mysql'.* TO 'root'@'%'` in addition to the above two lines, but I still get the same error.  It may be worth repeating that this is not the server; if there are any remote/local settings they may be relevant here.

Comment: And thank you for trying so hard to help.  It's a frustrating error, but at least I have help.

Comment: It's 2017. If anyone ended up here struggling with the issue in `mariadb`, please try `GRANT INSERT, CREATE ROUTINE ON mysql.* TO 'user'@'localhost`. The insert seem to be required as well as create routine.